# How to skip a custom __getattribute__ method?

Tags: python

To better understand the question, here is an example:

```
class Parent:
    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        print('ha!')
        return super().__getattribute__(attr)


class Bar(Parent):
    my_attr = 'hi'

test = Bar()

print("----------")
print(test.my_attr)
```

In this example, the `Bar` object has the `Parent` superclass that can't be changed.

Always when I read an attribute of an object of `Bar` type, this attribute first passes through the `__getattribute__` of the superclass `Parent`.

And the result printed of that code is:

```
----------
ha!
hi
```

But how can I read the original value of  `test` without going through `Parent`'s `__getattribute__`?

Comment: `my_attr` is a class attribute; you can just access it with `Bar.my_attr` instead of going through an instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `object.__getattribute__(test, 'my_attr')`
or `super(Parent, test).__getattribute__('my_attr')`.

Untested. But I have used this in my transposed object demo. To access the attributes on a object that proxies all access to calls on a collection.

Comment: Thank you! Any preference between these two solutions? I think I'll choose the first one because referencing the `Parent` object may add a bit of overhead.

Comment: I was about to suggest something like this. An obvious follow-on question is whether there's any way get it to automatically happen so `test.my_attr` does it?